# removing rows in pandas based on a column's values

Tags: python, pandas

This is a subset of a dataframe:

```
index  drug_id     values
1      le.1         f
2      le.7         h
3      le.10        9
4      le.11        10
5      le.15        S
```

I am going to remove rows that values in the drug_id column are: `le.7, le.10, le.11.` 
This is my code:

```
df.drop(df.drug_id[['le.7', 'le.10', 'le.11']], inplace = True )
```

I also tried this:

```
df.drop(df.drug_id == ['le.7', 'le.10', 'le.11'], inplace = True )
```

But none of them worked. Any suggestion ?

Comment: `df[~df.drug_id.isin(['le.7', 'le.10', 'le.11'])]` - it is dupe :(

Comment: Who is faster... jezrael's answer or Zero's closure.... hahaha!